# remove javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript

I use some kind of a library that declare

```
slide.prototype.removeClick= function(){
//something here
}
```

How to remove the prototype of removeClick in my js file? I can comment out or delete that chunk in the library js but that's not a good practice.

Comment: @torazaburo seriously? can't I just set it to null or something? I don't want to modify the plugin.js because I have to reuse it on somehwer else.

Comment: Why would you remove it? Can't you just ignore it?

Comment: @torazaburo says I have 2 module using that plugin, I will have plugin.js and plugin2.js. What's if I have 10 module need to use that plugin, I will have to have 10 different version of that js.

Answer (score 1):

Since presumably some code is going to call that function and you probably don't want a script error to occur at that point, you can just replace the existing 
function with your own dummy function by just reassigning the removeClick method to a new dummy function:

```
slide.prototype.removeClick = function(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `delete slide.prototype.removeClick` or `slide.prototype.removeClick = null`

Simplest way without intrusion

Answer (score 0):

here function created using **'Prototype'** is a kind of **'Object'**
and we have facility of deleting object so as @jfriend00 said you can delete it using **'delete'**.

and i would suggest if you are not gonna use that prototype function then just delete that particular lines of code man..!!! that will reduce your Complexity.